# How can I fix my script, that selenium finds the existing code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I tried, to scrape the in stock sizes from the following website. https://www.sivasdescalzo.com/de/p/wmns-jordan-delta-2-cw0913-101
For this I use Python and selenium. But the script never find the code, even if it exists.
So I do not get an error, I just get [] as output.

```py
def get_shoelinks(url_final):
    driverService = Service('/Users/flo/Desktop/Python/Webdriver/chromedriver')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driverService)
    driver.get(url_final)

    code_page = driver.page_source
    soup_page = BeautifulSoup(code_page, 'html.parser')

    main = soup_page.find('div', {'id':'root'})
    links = main.find_all('a', {'class': 'product-item-link set-product-storage'})




    time.sleep(5)

    sizes = []
    links_shoe = []

    for link in links:

        time.sleep(5)

        links_shoe.append(link['href'])
        driver.get(link['href'])
        sizes.append(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'swatch-option text'))

    return sizes


    driver.quit()

print(get_shoelinks(get_url()))
```

Does anybody has an idea, how I can fix this, so that I get the right output?

Comment: Provide more detail on the way your code fails, and also consider translating the variables to English when asking questions on a largely english-speaking forum

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Already changed it.

Answer (score 0):

This information is loaded with a request, for it sometimes can be difficult.
There is another way, if you find in the HTML code of this web, you can find the next code:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=swatch-options]": {
        "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
            "jsonConfig": {"attributes":{"138":{"id":"138","code":"size_us","label":"Gr\u00f6\u00dfe","options":[{"id":"160","label":"5.5","products":[]},{"id":"20","label":"6","products":[]},{"id":"165","label":"6.5","products":["523577"]},{"id":"18","label":"7","products":[]},{"id":"110","label":"7.5","products":["523583"]},{"id":"16","label":"8","products":[]},{"id":"121","label":"8.5","products":[]}],"position":"0"}},"template": 
            .....
        "Svd_Catalog/js/svd.swatch.renderer": {
            "jsonSwatchConfig": [{"option_id":"160","us":"5.5","eu":"36","uk":"3","cm":"22.5"},{"option_id":"20","us":"6","eu":"36.5","uk":"3.5","cm":"23"},{"option_id":"165","us":"6.5","eu":"37.5","uk":"4","cm":"23.5"},{"option_id":"18","us":"7","eu":"38","uk":"4.5","cm":"24"},{"option_id":"110","us":"7.5","eu":"38.5","uk":"5","cm":"24.5"},{"option_id":"16","us":"8","eu":"39","uk":"5.5","cm":"25"},{"option_id":"121","us":"8.5","eu":"40","uk":"6","cm":"25.5"}] }      
    },...
}</script>
 <script>
```

With it, you have different products. If you see in jsonConfig field, the attributes  165 and 110 have the field product populate, with it you have the different attributes with the US size.

If you want EU, UK and CM size, you can take these ids (165 and 110), and find them in jsonSwatchConfig field and filter option_id by these ids.

Regards,

Francisco.

Comment: Hi, first of all I appreciate your answer, but I do not understand, how I can implement this in to my code and what it actually does. Could you give me an example, how to do it?